# What's the difference between throttle and debounce in Rxswift3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have seen a lot of blogs about throttle and debounce. Most of them said they are the same thing. But I get the different result form my example? Here is the example:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
Observable.of(1,2,3,4,5)
          .debounce(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
          .subscribe(onNext: {print($0)})
          .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

the result was 5. But when I used throttle, the result was 1

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
Observable.of(1,2,3,4,5)
        .throttle(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: {print($0)})
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

So,I can't understand about the throttle operator?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In earlier versions of RxSwift, `throttle` and `debounce` did the same thing, which is why you will see articles stating this.  In RxSwift 3.0 they do a similar but opposite thing.

Both `debounce` and `throttle` are used to filter items emitted by an observable over time.

- `throttle` emits only the first item emitted by the source observable in the time window.
- `debounce` only emits an item after the specified time period has passed without another item being emitted by the source observable.

Both can be used to reduce the number of items emitted by an observable; which one you use depends on whether you want the "first" or "last" value emitted in a time period.

The term "debounce" comes from electronics and refers to the tendency of switch contacts to "bounce" between on and off very quickly when a switching action occurs.  You won't notice this when you turn on a lightbulb but a microprocessor looking at an input thousands of times a second will see a rapid sequence of "ons" and "offs" before the switch settles into its final state.  This is why `debounce` gives you the value of `5`; the final item that was emitted in your time frame (1 ms).  If you put a time delay into your code so that the items were emitted more slowly (more than 1ms apart) you would see a number of items emitted by `debounce`.

In an app you could use `debounce` for performing a search that is expensive (say it requires a network operation). The user is going to type a number of characters characters for their search string but you don't want to initiate a search as they enter each character, since the search is expensive and the earlier results will be obsolete by the time they return.  Using `debounce` you can ensure that the search string is only emitted once the user stops typing for a period (say 500ms).

You might use `throttle` where an operation takes some time and you want to ignore further input until that time has elapsed.  Say you have a button that initiates an operation.  If the user taps the button multiple times in quick succession you only want to initiate the operation once.  You can use `throttle` to ignore the subsequent taps within a specified time window.  `debounce` could also work but would introduce a delay before the action item was emitted, while `throttle` allows you to react to the first action and ignore the rest.

Comment: well explained, `throttle` will take the first immediately, while `debounce` will take the last after the window duration

Answer (score 2):

Simple explanation is here https://medium.com/fantageek/throttle-vs-debounce-in-rxswift-86f8b303d5d4

**Throttle**: the original function is called at most once per specified period.

**Debounce**: the original function is called after the caller stops calling the decorated function after a specified period.